# Can ancillary data be portably allocated?

Tags: sockets, posix, portability

[IEEE Std 1003.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/)'s [`<sys/socket.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html) section doesn't provide the CMSG_SPACE or CMSG_LEN macros, and instead merely says:

> Ancillary data consists of a sequence of pairs, each consisting of a
>   cmsghdr structure followed by a data array.

Is there a portable way to allocate ancillary data without CMSG_SPACE, or to attach ancillary data to a message without CMSG_LEN? That quote suggests to me that a single buffer with size `(sizeof(struct cmsghdr)+ sizeof data)*nr_of_pairs` (where data may change per pair, of course), with each individual `cmgshdr.cmsglen = sizeof(struct cmsghdr) + sizeof data` and `msg.msg_controllen = (sizeof(struct cmsghdr)+ sizeof data)*nr_of_pairs`, but all of the system-specific documentation for CMSG_SPACE/CMSG_LEN suggests that there are alignment issues that may get in the way of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so from what I can tell my guess as to how to allocate wouldn't work in general (I couldn't get it to work on Linux, I had to use CMSG_SPACE/CMSG_LEN instead). Based on the diagram in section 4.2 of [rfc2292](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2292.txt), I came up with the following definitions for CMSG_SPACE and CMSG_LEN that I think should be portable to conforming implementations of IEEE Std 1003.1-2008:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#ifndef CMSG_LEN
socklen_t CMSG_LEN(size_t len) {
        return (CMSG_DATA((struct cmsghdr *) NULL) - (unsigned char *) NULL) + len;
}
#endif

#ifndef CMSG_SPACE
socklen_t CMSG_SPACE(size_t len) {
        struct msghdr msg;
        struct cmsghdr cmsg;
        msg.msg_control = &cmsg;
        msg.msg_controllen =  ~0ULL; /* To maximize the chance that CMSG_NXTHDR won't return NULL */
        cmsg.cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(len);
        return (unsigned char *) CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, &cmsg) - (unsigned char *) &cmsg;
}
#endif
```

Obvously this should be done with macros, but I think this shows the idea. This seems really hacky to me and, due to possible size checks in CMSG_NXTHDR, can't be shoved into a compile-time constant, so probably the next version of POSIX should define CMSG_SPACE and CMSG_LEN since any program using ancillary data has to use them anyway.